# accesing many to many fields in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, many-to-many

i am trying to build a clothes online store as a fun side project while studying django, i have products each of these products has multiple instances where each instance has a color and a size, like one usually sees in a clothes store, i am using many to one relationship to represent the relation between product and its multiple instances also, i am using many to many relationship to represent the relation between each instance and its color and size because many instances of a product could have many colors and a color could have many products, the same goes for the size.

i have tried many solutions that i have found online but none have worked, here is my implementation.

model.py

```
class Size(models.Model):
    size_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.size_name


class Color(models.Model):
    color_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.color_name


class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(Sub_category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name


class productInstanceDetail(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, related_name="product_instance", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    size = models.ManyToManyField(Size, related_name="product_instance_size")
    color = models.ManyToManyField(Color, related_name="product_instance_color")
    in_stock = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(default=0)
    sold = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.product_name
```

views.py

```
def product_detail_view(request, category_id, sub_category_id, pk):
    template_name = "hareswear/product.html"
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, id=category_id)
    sub_category = get_object_or_404(Sub_category, id=sub_category_id)
    productObject = get_object_or_404(Product, id=pk)
    print(productObject.product_name)
    product_Instance_Detail_list = []
    listOfInstances = []
    for prodInst in productInstanceDetail.objects.filter(product=productObject):
        print(prodInst)
        print("it should print here")
        product_Instance_Detail_list.append(prodInst.sold)
        product_Instance_Detail_list.append(prodInst.in_stock)
        for col in Color.objects.filter(productinstancedetail_id=prodInst.pk).all():
            product_Instance_Detail_list.append(col.color_name)
        for size in Size.objects.filter(productinstancedetail_id=prodInst.pk).all():
            product_Instance_Detail_list.append(size.size_name)
        listOfInstances.append(product_Instance_Detail_list)
        print(product_Instance_Detail_list)

    print(listOfInstances)
    context = {
        "category": category,
        "sub_category": sub_category,
        "product": productObject,
        "instances_details": listOfInstances,
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

i want to send to the template the category of the product, its subcategory and the product object itself, all of this is working, what isn't working is accessing the color and size of the product instance, i know my implementation here isn't ideal but i have tried alot of other approaches and none have worked.

i also want to point out the in the views.py, the prints statements inside the for loops is not printing which makes me feel like the loop isn't looping (????? like what???) i have tried using .all() in this line `for prodInst in productInstanceDetail.objects.filter(product=productObject):`
but it still doesn't work.